# relative pronouns, to infinitive, present participle. Are they interchangeable?

Tags: relative-pronouns, to-infinitive, present-participles

1. Armstrong was the first man who walked on the moon.
2. Armstrong was the first man to walk on the moon.
3. Armstrong was the first man walking on the moon.

Are they all the same?  If not, what it the difference?

Answer (score 1):

The second sentence is better. The focus of the sentence is on first performance. The third sentence slightly shifts that focus to what was being performed, namely the rather commonplace activity of walking. The first sentence is slightly verbose and thus not quite as emphatic as the second.